# how to i pass data of registration form and upload image in registration form with validation and through ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am making a single registration form with all the data and input tags I need and pass that data to the next page via AJAX. But I do not get my image upload value to the next page. Please help me find a solution regarding `ajaxfileupload.js` and `validation.js` and tell me how to store image in a database using codeigniter.

```
<script src="<?php echo JS_PATH;?>jquery-validation.js"></script>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#registration_form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            surname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your name"
            },
            surname: "Please enter your surname",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: submitForm
    });

    function submitForm() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var surname = $('#surname').val();
        var age = $('#age').val();
        var dob = $('#datepicker').val();
        var ph_no = $('#ph_no').val();
        var gender = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
        var hobbies = new Array();
        $('input[name="hobbies[]"]:checked').each(function() {
            hobbies.push(this.value);
        });
        var city = $('#city').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var pwd = $('#password').val();
        var photo = $("#userfile").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo SITE_ROOT;?>Registration/insertdata",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                username: name,
                user_surname: surname,
                user_email: email,
                password: pwd,
                user_age: age,
                user_dob: dob,
                user_ph_no: ph_no,
                user_gender: gender,
                user_hobbies: hobbies,
                user_city: city,
                user_photo: photo
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**html:**

```
<form method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" > 
    <label> File Input: </label> 
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**php controller:**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Registration extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('menupages/registration_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->first();
    }

    function first() {
        $data['title'] = "Registration Page";
        $this->load->view('menupages/registration', $data);
    }

    function insertdata() {
        $file = $_POST['user_photo'];
        print_r($file);
        exit();
        $config['upload_path'] = '/var/www/html/upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['file_name'] = $file;
        $this->load->library('upload'); //initialize 
        $this->upload->initialize($config); 
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))  {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($error);
            exit(); 
        }  else  {   
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
            print_r($data);
            exit();  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please help me how can i use both validation.js and AjaxFileUpload .js on same page without submit on page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make use of FormData() on javascript.

---

```
data = new FormData();

data.append('name', $('#name').val());
data.append('surname', $('#surname').val());
data.append('age', $('#age').val());
data.append('dob', $('#datepicker').val());
data.append('ph_no', $('#ph_no').val());
data.append('gender', $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val());

//for Photo
data.append('photo', $('#userfile')[0].files[0]);


//AJAX
$.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo SITE_ROOT;?>Registration/insertdata",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
```

PHP CODE:
To test if you successfully passed file and post data on php:

print_r($_FILES);
 print_r($_POST);

Comment: this , does not answer the op's question , see my answer , the formData  , i have already included , and there were also php errors in op's code.

Comment: i try your code it's give data by$_FILES. but it not working with  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) its give error : Array
(
    [error] => <p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>
)

Comment: this part of code is not working: $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($error);exit();
        }  else  {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            print_r($data);exit();
        }

Comment: try not using codeigniter upload helper. try using this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

First of all , there are many things that are not okay with your current code inside php codeginiter 's controller, let's first see a difference between `$_POST` vs `$_FILES`

[$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) contains all the data from forms (except files)

[$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) contains all files sent to server via forms (only from `<input type="file" />`)

What you are doing is , you are using `$_POST['user_photo']` to fetch the file details , which is not okay to fetch the file information for uploading it. And also another thing is :

```
 $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
```

You are wrong here. the parameter `userfile` does not even exist in your http request. While sending the data to the server , you have replaced the `userfile` with `user_photo` , so what you have to here is also you have to change these two things

```
$_POST['user_photo']; 
$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
```

to

```
$_FILES['user_photo']; 
$this->upload->do_upload('user_photo');
```

change your :

```
 $('#userfile').val();
```

to

```
 $("#userfile").prop("files")[0];
```

and add these parameters into javascript parameters along with url , data and etc..

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
cache: false,
```

change your submitForm function to this:

```
function submitForm() {
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var surname = $('#surname').val();
                var age = $('#age').val();
                var dob = $('#datepicker').val();
                var ph_no = $('#ph_no').val();
                var gender = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
                var hobbies = new Array();
                $('input[name="hobbies[]"]:checked').each(function() {
                    hobbies.push(this.value);
                });
                var city = $('#city').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var pwd = $('#password').val();
                var photo = $("#userfile").prop("files")[0];

                var form_data = new FormData();
                form_data.append("user_photo", photo);
                form_data.append("username",name);
                form_data.append("user_surname",surname);
                form_data.append("password",pwd);
                form_data.append("user_age",age);
                form_data.append("user_dob",dob);
                form_data.append("user_ph_no",ph_no);
                form_data.append("user_gender",gender);
                form_data.append("user_hobbies",hobbies);
                form_data.append("user_city",city);
                $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo SITE_ROOT;?>Registration/insertdata",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: I follow your suggestion and put  print_r($_FILES['photo_user']);exit(); in my controller but i got this error: undefine index photo_user

Comment: @NishitaPatel Reminding: replace `$_POST['name']` with `$this->input->post('name')` which is more secure for your website.

Comment: I add script that you give me but it still give error undefine index:user_photo for $_file

Comment: No no no ,,, wrong method totally , let me show you , how to send the inputs along with file.

Comment: @NishitaPatel  check my answer update , and replace your whole submitForm with the one that i have posted in answer

Comment: i try your suggested code but  i don't get output by $FILES['user_photo'];

Comment: @NishitaPatel  it's $_FILES['user_photo']  not $FILES['user_photo']

Answer (score -1):

You can submit the form and send it by form.serialize in JQuery. It will send data with picture by Ajax.